# Why are there two different HTML entities formats and what is their difference?

Tags: html-entities, html-encode

When I was encoding some text to HTML entities, I noticed there were two formats. For example, the string

```
ç á ê
```

can get encoded to

```
&ccedil; &aacute; &ecirc;
```

or

```
&#231; &#225; &#234;
```

Is there any advantage of one over the other? Why are there two formats?

Comment: One basic advantage is that the html encoding is easier to remember, plus it's no worse than the other.

Answer (score 1):

One is the unicode values for those characters and the other is shorthand that HTML defines for these specific characters.  Same end result but the first example is certainly easier for us humans to understand when looking at the code (without cross referencing something like http://www.unicode.org/charts/).  You'd normally only use the unicode approach for characters that don't have shorthand equivalents.